# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, stat

Tags: javascript, flutter, npm

I recently started using Firebase Functions for my Flutter project.

I saw that there is a code generator ([firebase_functions_interop](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_functions_interop)) that will transform your Dart code to Javascript code. This enables you to develop your cloud functions in Dart which is pretty nice.

But after developing my first cloud function and trying to deploy it to Firebase with the Firebase CLI, I constantly get the following error message:

`Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, stat 'C:\PATH_TO_MY_FIREBASE_PROJECT\build\node\packages'`

I'm new to npm & Firebase Functions so maybe I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

It looks like something about permissions maybe? I don't know. But I also have full permissions on my workspace folder & have enabled VSCode as an Administrator

I have already tried to clean my npm cache & reinstalling my npm version.

Let me know if you need me to post anything else.

Answer (score 2):

make sure you do not have the firebase emulator running! it will cause this error when trying to do a deployment to the firebase cloud.